# Implementing IEquatable with T4-templates, database-first approach in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, t4, ef-database-first

I'm trying to get all my entities to implement 'IEquatable', but I'm stuck with T4-templates:

I've changed the opening-method already to the following:

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}{4}{5}",
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        _code.Escape(entity),
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)),
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType))) ? _code.StringBefore(" : ", "BaseEntity<" + _code.Escape(entity) + ">") : "",
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.StringBefore(", ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType))) ? _code.StringBefore(", ", "IEquatable<" + _code.Escape(entity) + ">") : "");
}
```

Which gaves me, e.g. `public partial class TableName : BaseEntity<TableName>, IEquatable<TableName>` whereas BaseEntity is just a wrapper-class.

What I now need is to create the implementation of `IEquatable` which should look like:

```
#region implementation of IEquatable

/// <summary>
/// Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// true if the current object is equal to the <paramref name="other"/> parameter; otherwise, false.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="other">An object to compare with this object.</param>
public bool Equals(TableName other) => TableNameId == other.TableNameId;

#endregion
```

with the region, the comment and the statement itself. My table-naming convention allows to build the id-property by prefixing `Id` with the name of the table, so MyTable -> MyTableId, OtherTable -> OtherTableId.
Only 2 or 3 tables do not follow these convention so I need also a check for the the current `entity`, like:

```
// check if we have an 'special' entity
if(currentEntity.Name == "NonDefaultTable"){
    // set Equals to return NonDefaultTableKey == other.NonDefaultTableKey;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Watch out if you override Equals on Entity classes. EF uses Equals internally to decided whether an Entity must be created/updated/deleted (Changetracker). Therefore Equals should always incorporate the primary key, or you might write to the wrong table row in the DB.

Comment: I'm aware of this and the `Equals` will always return the PK of the table so this should be fine.